# Use devise password to restrict method in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to restrict some of my user's action with their user account password.
I have a transfer controller, and users can transfer money using the create method in the transfer controller.

I would like to require the password everytime the user click on the transfer button to validate the transfer but I could not find anything related to that on the web.

I want to add a password field to the views and process the transfer only if the password is the user account password.

I am using devise for managing my users account.

How could I do that ?

Thanks,

Form :

```
<%= form_for current_user.transfers.build do |f| %>
<div class="amount">
    <h5>Select an amount</h5>
    <div class="amount-btns">
        <a class="amount-btn" href="#"><span data-amount="10">10&#36;</span></a>
        <a class="amount-btn" href="#"><span data-amount="20">20&#36;</span></a>
        <a class="amount-btn" href="#"><span data-amount="30">30&#36;</span></a>
        <a class="amount-btn" href="#"><span data-amount="50">50&#36;</span></a>
        <%= f.hidden_field :amount, :id => :amount %>
        <%#= f.hidden_field :teen_id , :id => :user_id_auto_donation %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="choose-amount">
    <div class="choose-amnt" action="#">
        <div class="form-row choose-lnk">
            <%= f.collection_select :teen_id, current_user.followed_users, :id, :first_name , include_blank: false, :prompt => 'Select a Teen' %>
        </div>

            <%= hidden_field_tag :no_card if !current_user.customer_id? %>
            <%= password_field(:password, :password, :size => 20, :class => 'form_input') %>
            <%= f.submit 'Send', :class => "orange-btn", :id => "send_donation"%>
<% end %>
```

Transfer_Controller :

```
def create
 Rails.logger.debug(params[:password])
 Rails.logger.debug(current_user.valid_password?(params[:password]))
if current_user.valid_password?(params[:password])
....
else
redirect_to :back
end
```

Rails.logger.debug(params[:password]) return the password I entered and the one that is correct.

Rails.logger.debug(current_user.valid_password?(params[:password])) return false but if I relplace the params[:password] with the actual password it return true

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials) that shows you how to check user credentials,
for your case you will do something like the following (given that you send the password as a parameter named 'password'):

```
# use the return value to determine if the user inserted the correct password
if(current_user.valid_password?(params[:password]))
  # create transfer
else
  # tell user password is invalid
end
```

Comment: So that's what I did but no matter what I do the password validation fails and goes into the else. I added a password field :     <%= password_field(:password, :size => 20, :class => 'form_input') %>  and then in my transfers controller used : if(current_user.valid_password?(params[:password])), Thanks

Comment: make sure the params[:password] actually contains the password entered by the user, you can post the code of your form here so we can check it.
use Rails.logger.debug(params[:password]) in your action to see what is sent, and check the logger.

Comment: Ok found the solution params[:password][:password] works better ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Or I can also use password_field_tag instead of password_field with just params[:password] Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be better and more readable, you are welcome